# Unregistering a callback registered via register_callback()?

Tags: c++, iostream

I'm using [`register_callback()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios_base/register_callback/) to register a call-back function for iostreams as described in
[Standard C++ IOStreams and Locales](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321585585), p. 202.

However, neither it nor any documentation I could find say how one can unregister a call-back. Is it possible? If I were to zero-out the iword/pword I'm using, is unregistering even necessary?

Comment: +1 for trying to use something which I didn't even know exist.

Comment: Brave. All the advanced iostream stuff is basically uncharged territory. There is a single book on the subject, but few people other than the authors have ever really dug into the nitty gritty details.

Comment: @jalf: That may be because IOstreams just generally suck. :) They may be powerful and really extensible, but they are convoluted and complicated. Sadly, there doesn't seem to be any movement regarding a new I/O style/library.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The register_callback function registers your callback for a specific stream object. The way to get rid of the registration is to let the stream go out of scope.

If you need your callback to do its work for just a part of the stream's lifetime, you can store that condition with the callback and make it do nothing.

Clearing iword/pword doesn't help (except that it could be a signal to the callback to do nothing), and there is no way to unregister.

Comment: Option #1 (stream going out of scope) isn't an option for a stream like cout.

Option #2 (storing a condition with the callback) seems problematic since it's just an ordinary function and not a functor object, hence there's really no good place to store additional information.  (The same callback can be used by multiple streams.)

Option #3 (clearing iword/pword) is what I'm doing now. I just wanted to see if there were something better.